# How do I create an editable table in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, tableview

how do I create a table on a view (see screenshot)? The user should be able to edit/ put some data into the textfields. I tried to recreate it by adding multiple VStacks and HStacks but my Xcode started complaining pretty fast.

I hope anyone can help me with this. It should be noted that there will be a few of such tables, so the user will be giving much input (just in case it has some effect on app performance). It will be inside of a ScrollView and a NavigationView.

Anyway, I appreciate any kind of Advice and thanks in Advance!
Kind Regards

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiFRc.png)

Comment: Look at a `LazyVGrid`.

Comment: This is a very legitimate question and the answer is spot on. Not sure who closes these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always, @Yrb is absolutely right. And here is how it could look like:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var inputFields: [String] = Array(repeating: "", count: 24)
    
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 20)), count: 7)
    let rowTitles = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            
            // first headline row
            Text("")
            ForEach(1..<7) { i in
                Text("\(i)").bold()
            }
            
            // rows
            ForEach(0..<4) { row in
                Text(rowTitles[row]).font(.title)
                ForEach(0..<6) { col in
                    TextField("", text: $inputFields[row * 6 + col])
                        .background(
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Color.primary
                                    .frame(height: 1)
                            }
                        )
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much, it worked. Im new, but is it still manageable for an app with a few of these in a view?

Comment: should be no problem at all

Comment: Great, Thank You!